# Python Lists - different results for L1+=[5] and L1 = L1+[5]

Tags: python, list

I had learnt about the Mutability of Lists and was trying to see how it works. 
However, I observed something new:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x
print x # [1, 2, 3]
y += [3, 2, 1]
print x # [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

works all right

However, if I replace **y += [3,2,1]** by **y = y + [3,2,1]**, I get the following result:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x
print x # [1, 2, 3]
y = y+ [3, 2, 1]
print x # [1, 2, 3]
```

which isn't what I had expected. Can someone please tell me how y+= is giving a different result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been answered somewhere before, but long story short:

`x = x + y` means basically assign `x+y` to `x` (so `x` references a new object)

`x += y` means add `y` to `x` (so `x` still references the same object)

Answer (score 1):

when you do:

```
y = y+ [3, 2, 1]
```

you are creating a new list y with new reference, and that does not affect the old one.